# improve django queryset performance

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a set of products that I need to fetch from my API, along with their respective discounts. Initially, I used the **`subqueries`** approach to achieve this, but it has led to significant performance issues as the dataset has grown. I'm looking for suggestions on how to refactor the queryset to improve the performance. Any ideas or alternative methods to efficiently retrieve product discounts would be greatly appreciated.

This is the QuerySet:

```
active_vouchers = Voucher.dal.get_active_vouchers(
    voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based
).prefetch_related('voucher_ranges__packs__expense')

is_discounted_subquery = active_vouchers.filter(
    voucher_ranges__packs__product__id=OuterRef('pk'), min_basket_value=0
    )

voucher_type = is_discounted_subquery.filter(voucher_ranges__packs__product__id=OuterRef('pk')).\
    values('voucher_type')[:1]

voucher_kind = is_discounted_subquery.filter(voucher_ranges__packs__product__id=OuterRef('pk')).\
    values('voucher_kind')[:1]

voucher_fixed_amount = Voucher.bll.convert_voucher_fixed_price_currency(active_vouchers, currency.code).\
    filter(voucher_ranges__packs__product__id=OuterRef('pk'),
).values('converted_fixed_price')[:1]

voucher_percent_amount = is_discounted_subquery.filter(
    voucher_ranges__packs__product__id=OuterRef('pk'),
).values('value_percentage_based')[:1]

qs = self.annotate(
    is_discounted=Case(
        When(
            Q(Exists(is_discounted_subquery)),
            then=True,
        ),
        default=False
    ),
    voucher_kind=Case(
        When(
            Q(is_discounted=True),
            then=Subquery(voucher_kind)
        ),
        default=Value('no_voucher')
    ),
    voucher_type=Case(
        When(
            Q(is_discounted=True),
            then=Subquery(voucher_type)
        ),
        default=Value('no_voucher')
    ),
    fixed_static_discount=Case(
    When(Q(
            is_discounted=True,
            voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based,
            voucher_type=VoucherTypeChoices.Fixed_price_based
            ),
        then=Subquery(voucher_fixed_amount)
        ),
    default=0,
    output_field=MoneyCurrencyOutput(currency)
    ),
    percentage_static_discount=Case(
    When(Q(
            is_discounted=True,
            voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based,
            voucher_type=VoucherTypeChoices.Percentage_based
            ),
        then=Subquery(voucher_percent_amount)
        ),
    default=0,
    ),
    price_after_static_discount=Case(
        When(
            Q(
                is_discounted=True,
                voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based,
                voucher_type=VoucherTypeChoices.Fixed_price_based),
            then=ExpressionWrapper(
                F('default_pack_price') - F('fixed_static_discount'),
                output_field=MoneyCurrencyOutput(currency),
            )
        ),
        When(
            Q(
                is_discounted=True,
                voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based,
                voucher_type=VoucherTypeChoices.Percentage_based),
            then=ExpressionWrapper(
                F('default_pack_price') * (100 - F('percentage_static_discount')) / 100,
                output_field=MoneyCurrencyOutput(currency),
            )
        ),
    default=0,
    output_field=MoneyCurrencyOutput(currency)
    ),
)
return qs
```

This the QuerySet explain and the query in SQL:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/xIgD#source

Im not sure why planning time is taking too long, the problem might be because of my config on postgres on docker so this is the config that i use:

```
jit = off

# Memory Configuration
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 2GB
work_mem = 5MB
maintenance_work_mem = 102MB

# Checkpoint Related Configuration
min_wal_size = 2GB
max_wal_size = 3GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = -1

# Network Related Configuration
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 1000

# Storage Configuration
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200

# Worker Processes Configuration
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 2
```

UPDATE 1:
These are the models:

voucher range:

```
class VoucherRange(TimeStampMixin, TruncateMixin):
    voucher = models.OneToOneField(
        'Voucher',
        verbose_name=_('voucher'),
        related_name='voucher_ranges',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        help_text=_('The voucher this voucher range belongs to.')
    )
    packs = models.ManyToManyField(
        'warehouse.Pack',
        verbose_name=_('packs'),
        related_name='voucher_ranges',
        help_text=_('Access to the related pack(s) of a voucher range.'),
        blank=True
    )
```

Voucher:

```
class Voucher(TitleSlugDescriptionMixin, TimeStampMixin, TruncateMixin):
    voucher_kind = models.CharField(
        _('voucher kind'),
        max_length=20,
        validators=[MaxLengthValidator(20)],
        choices=VoucherKindChoices.choices,
        help_text=_('Determines what kind of voucher is.')
    )
    voucher_type = models.CharField(
        _('voucher type'),
        max_length=20,
        validators=[MaxLengthValidator(20)],
        choices=VoucherTypeChoices.choices,
        help_text=_('Determines what type of voucher is.')
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        _('status'),
        max_length=20,
        validators=[MaxLengthValidator(20)],
        choices=VoucherStatusChoices.choices,
        help_text=_('Status of the voucher.')
    )
    value_fixed_price_based = MoneyField(
        _('fixed price based'),
        max_digits=14,
        decimal_places=2,
        default_currency=DEFAULT_CURRENCY_SHOW_ON_SITE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_('If the voucher type is fixed price based, '
                    'it takes the value of the money type.')
    )
    value_percentage_based = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        _('percentage based'),
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)],
        default=0,
        help_text=_('If the voucher type is percentage based, '
                    'takes the value between 0 to 100 percent.')
    )
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(
        _('start datetime'),
        help_text=_('The release date or the start of the voucher.')
    )
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(
        _('end datetime'),
        help_text=_('The expiry date or the end of the voucher.')
    )
```

And then I have `Pack` and `Expense` model, which before voucher QuerySet I call another function to get `default_pack_price` from `Expense` model for each `Pack` instance in my qs.

UPDATE 2:

my `get_active_vouchers`:

```
def get_unexpired_voucher(self):
    current_time = timezone.now().replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    return self.filter(start_time__lte=current_time, end_time__gte=current_time)

def get_active_vouchers(self,
                        voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based):
    return self.get_voucher_status(VoucherStatusChoices.Open).\
                get_unexpired_voucher().\
                filter(voucher_kind=voucher_kind)
```

any my `convert_voucher_fixed_price_currency`:

```
def convert_voucher_fixed_price_currency(self, active_vouchers, currency: str) -> QuerySet:
    if any(x in ['makemigrations', 'migrate', 'reset'] for x in sys.argv):
        return active_vouchers.annotate(
        converted_fixed_price=Value(0)
        )

    currencies = active_vouchers.values_list("value_fixed_price_based_currency", flat=True)
    # todo : user the base function (class) for converting currency
    converted_rates_dict = {
        _currency: convert_currency(input_currency=_currency,
                                    output_currency=currency,
                                    only_return_rate=True
                                ) for _currency in currencies}

    # for those that are the same currency with the given currency
    converted_rates_dict.update({currency: 1})

    case_when_list = list()

    for dict_currency, rate in converted_rates_dict.items():
        case_when_list.append(
                        When(
                            Q(value_fixed_price_based_currency=dict_currency) and \
                            Q(voucher_type__iexact=VoucherTypeChoices.Fixed_price_based),
                            then=F('value_fixed_price_based') * rate),
        )

    return active_vouchers.annotate(
        converted_fixed_price=Case(
            *case_when_list,
            output_field=MoneyCurrencyOutput(currency),
            default=0
        ))
```

Comment: Sometimes when there are more active user then performance issue is seen. Everyone hits the page and the long big query starts to hit the database. Did you try splitting the query into multiple queries and giving some load on application server instead of database server?

Comment: Can you elaborate which part of provided code takes the most time? Did you make sure that code just runs **once** and not by mistake multiple times?

Comment: Honestly I would like to see the setup of your model structure. There should be a super easy way to find Vouchers related to this `OuterRef` thingy. But I need to know the relations. (I don't need to see the entire model, just the Voucher model and the OuterRef model and how they are "linked" (eg. by ForeignKey).)

Comment: @Manan Thanks for answering, This is all on docker instances on develop environment so there are no users. and about splitting the query, Im not sure if thats gonna have any impact at all since it needs the previous queries data to get other data. can you be more specific?

Comment: @Tarquinius These are all subqueries so can't really tell which part is causing the problem, that's why I uploaded the explain as well, but I don't have the knowledge to understand whats the problem from that queryset explain. but you can see all the joins and costs for each part of the code on that. and i updated the models that you asked for.

Comment: And what is `Voucher.dal` and `Voucher.bll`?

Comment: @Tarquinius dll and bll are my custom managers, I updated the question with functions that are used.

Comment: Have you tried denormalization or some sort of CQRS approach?

Comment: @MuriloSitonio I did not know anything about those, did some research, but Im not sure how to use or implement them or how can those be helpful?

Comment: In this API, are you paginating the products? If you are using DRF, it might be worth trying out prefetching all the voucher info per product, and then do all your processing on the serializer at django level rather than the DB level

Comment: @BrianDestura This actually works but only in scenarios with pagination and its not the final solution to this problem, but can i annotate to a prefetched queryset? like use the prefetched attribute for my annotations in the queryset.

Answer (score -1):

Try this refactored queryset.

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Subquery, When, Case, F, Q, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

active_vouchers = Voucher.objects.filter(
    voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based,
    voucher_ranges__packs__product__id=OuterRef('pk'),
    voucher_ranges__packs__min_basket_value=0,
).distinct()

discount_subquery = active_vouchers.filter(
    voucher_ranges__packs__product__id=OuterRef('pk')
).values('voucher_type', 'voucher_kind')[:1]

qs = self.annotate(
    is_discounted=Exists(discount_subquery),
    voucher_type=Subquery(discount_subquery.values('voucher_type')),
    voucher_kind=Subquery(discount_subquery.values('voucher_kind')),
    voucher_fixed_amount=Coalesce(
        Subquery(
            Voucher.bll.convert_voucher_fixed_price_currency(
                active_vouchers, currency.code
            ).values('converted_fixed_price')[:1]
        ), Value(0)
    ),
    voucher_percent_amount=Subquery(
        active_vouchers.values('value_percentage_based')[:1]
    ),
    fixed_static_discount=Case(
        When(
            Q(is_discounted=True, voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based, voucher_type=VoucherTypeChoices.Fixed_price_based),
            then=F('voucher_fixed_amount')
        ),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=MoneyCurrencyOutput(currency)
    ),
    percentage_static_discount=Case(
        When(
            Q(is_discounted=True, voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based, voucher_type=VoucherTypeChoices.Percentage_based),
            then=F('voucher_percent_amount')
        ),
        default=Value(0),
    ),
    price_after_static_discount=Case(
        When(
            Q(is_discounted=True, voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based, voucher_type=VoucherTypeChoices.Fixed_price_based),
            then=F('default_pack_price') - F('fixed_static_discount')
        ),
        When(
            Q(is_discounted=True, voucher_kind=VoucherKindChoices.Static_based, voucher_type=VoucherTypeChoices.Percentage_based),
            then=F('default_pack_price') * (100 - F('percentage_static_discount')) / 100
        ),
        default=Value(0),
        output_field=MoneyCurrencyOutput(currency)
    ),
)

return qs
```

Comment: how is this even going to help ? i have performance problems